# PLACEHOLDER - Stack Exchange App to build Stack Overflow pack for Coda.io

Tags: app, placeholder

## Stack Overflow Coda Pack

A [coda.io](https://coda.io) pack for Stack Overflow integration. It includes formulas, sync tables and actions to fetch useful data and take actions from Stack Overflow API.

The pack is not published yet and will be published before the hackathon submission deadline.

This post was created to comply with Stack Exchange App requirements for write access.

In the meantime, until the pack is published, I made a temporary landing page https://coda.io/d/_dfO9tO_PB96/Stack-Overflow-Pack_su69w.

### Example use cases

- Track questions related to certain filter criteria.
- Import all your bookmarked questions.
- Bookmark questions directly from your coda document.

### Disclaimer

Please note that this app is my submission for the [Coda Hackathon](https://coda.devpost.com/)